# Can we change Android source code using Android NDK..?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am having a requirement like to add a custom setting to android native settings(like when we go to Home->settings->Display we have Screen timeout,Animation,Auto-rotate screen,Brightness settings available.But i want to add one more setting like auto-screentimeout there.i,e i need to change the source code of android..some thing related to forked android consept)so,Is this possible..?if so can we use NDK for this...
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the Android source code and then create your own settings APK. However it will probably only run on the phone you are testing it, and I assume you run into problems when using different Android versions or some modifications by device manufacturers.

Read more http://source.android.com/ on how to get started.

Alternatively you could extract the settings APK from your current phone, decompile it with apktools, and then re-create it again with your changes.

Read more on http://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/

In both ways you need to have root access to install the new APK... and probably a custom recovery to restore from a nandroid backup when your modification crashes!

Comment: can you please give me some more information regarding both the cases...especially apktools

Comment: when i use apktool to extract settings.apk iam not getting classes.dex file,but if i extract 3rd party application i am getting classes.dex.Without classes.dex iam unable to extract source code..please suggest me a solution ..

Comment: finally i created a custom settings.apk but when i install it in my device i am getting signature failed error,as the signing key used for my htc nexus one differs with my key but how to overcome this problem

Comment: it will not work if you just install it over the old settings.apk because they are signed with different certificates. You have to copy your new apk to /system/app and overwrite the original one. Then boot into recovery, clear dalvik cache, and try to reboot...

Comment: hey ram ,i did as you said .i just changed icon of native settings and tried to override the original one.Native settings is overrided with my customsettings,its is displayed in root explorer with changed icon but  icon is not displayed in home screen.When i try to launch it from menu its throwing error.

Answer (score 1):

The Android NDK is for writing **application** code in C or C++.

What you want is to build your own version of the Android firmware; it is a completely separate issue. Have a [look at this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1_H4AlQaNa0) for starters.

Comment: finally i created a custom settings.apk but when i install it in my device i am getting signature failed error,as the signing key used for my htc nexus one differs with my key but how to overcome this problem